# How to enable side and bottom slide of a touchpad on a Dell Studio 15?

Tags: windows-7, touchpad, scrollbar

I reformatted my hard drive and installed Windows 7 Home Premium on my laptop, and now I can't scroll with my touchpad like I used to by swiping down on the right side.

I installed the driver for the touchpad from the Dell website but it's still not working.

Comment: For some touchpad, we need to enable this functionality explicitly. Have a look at the touchpad properties.

Answer (score 0):

Switching OS versions can cause all kinds of driver issues for devices originally released with an older OS. The drivers may not always work as advertised.

**With most Dell computers**, there is a specific order to install drivers - [How to Download and Install Drivers in the Correct Order](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=us&docid=268873&doclang=en&l=en&s=gen&cs=).

Also, when choosing drivers, you may not be able to use the Windows 7 64 bit drivers. If you have a 32 bit OS, use the Windows Vista drivers (I believe you need the Synaptic drivers for that laptop).

Lastly, make sure you have all the Windows updates.

Answer (score -2):

In device manager, find the id string code for the hardware. Search for drivers based on this id-string, from the hardware manufacturer. The manufacturer of the hardware device may have more current drivers than the computer manufacturer.

Sometimes, a slightly newer model laptop with same hardware id, but bundled with an updated operating system, will have a more recent driver available. For example, with two laptops that were similar, but with different model names, I picked the business version that came with a newer Windows than mine. The laptop manufacturer did have the newer drivers for the newer laptop. The manufacturer never updated their database to include business or ultimate Windos 7.

Laptop motherboards are mass produced and often the same hardware is found in other laptops with new drivers. Cross referencing is very helpful. Microsoft also has a database for hardware and which windows drivers are good or never updated for newer windows. The Microsoft database shows if the driver works or not, and if there is a work around such as vista drivers with compatibility mode in windows 7 or 8. In a pinch I use an external mouse with a wheel.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) is somewhat difficult to understand.  Please edit it for clarity and consider focusing on the exact details required to address the OPs question.